# firefox doesn't automatically reset textarea values when you re-load the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have an issue where the the text in the text area is not displaying in Firefox but it displays in IE and Chrome.  The text is suppose to display so that I can edit/alter it.

when i do and inspect element in Firefox the "Text not displaying" is there but it just does not display in forms textarea.

Comment: Post the relevant code or make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: It works fine in all major browsers - http://jsfiddle.net/jHW88/. Note that there is no 'visible' attribute, so I don't know what you're trying to do there.

Comment: [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) elements don't have `visible` or `textmode` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the attribute `autocomplete="off"` in your `textarea` tag?

```
<textarea autocomplete="off" class="questionType txtResponse" visible="False" cols="1" rows="10"
  textmode="MultiLine" data-type="text" data-formautofail="0" data-sectionautofail="0" 
  data-points="0" data-question="1" data-autofailtype="0" data-section="1" 
  data-possiblepoints="0.00" name="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh in FireFox, input controls will remain as they were before the refresh... I believe this is by design (if anybody knows differently, please comment and I will update my answer).

Your best bet is to do a forced refresh by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> and you will see the input control return to their default values.